# Soap soap-enc:Array example (C#)

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I need to call a PHP Soap webservice in C#. I do have a WSDL but the main parts of input data are typed as **soap:enc:Array** resulting in **object[]**:

snippets from the WSDL for add_address:

```
<operation name="add_address">
  <documentation>
  Add's a new Address with the data provided in an array.
  </documentation>
  <input message="tns:add_addressIn"/>
  <output message="tns:add_addressOut"/>
</operation>

<message name="add_addressIn">
  <part name="data" type="soap-enc:Array"/>
  <part name="token" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>

<message name="add_addressOut">
  <part name="return" type="soap-enc:Array"/>
</message>
```

Importing the WSDL as a reference in Visual Studio results in a the type **object[]** for the **data** parameter in the add_Address function.

From the online docs of the webservice :

[image: dataExample]

Invoking from PHP (also as per their docs):

```
data = Array
(
    [company_name] => MDS Collivery
    [building] => MDS House
    [street] => 58c Webber St
    [location_type] => 5
    [suburb_id] => 1936
    [town_id] => 147
    [custom_id] => AF65549
    [full_name] => Bernhard Breytenbach
    [phone] => 0123456789
    [cellphone] => 0834567912
    [email] => name@domain.co.za
)
add_address(data, '4M8wJGBXC6KKpT0')
```

I have tried with a Dictionary in C# but that results in serialization challenges.

Importing the WSDL in SoapUI results in:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v2="https://www.collivery.co.za/ws/v2">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v2:add_contact soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <data xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
         </data>
         <token xsi:type="xsd:string">?</token>
      </v2:add_contact>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have written my own client to build up the Soap envelope. it works for all the strongly typed operation but I don't know how to build up the elements for **soap-enc:Array**

Can anyone please assist with providing an example of what to put within the  element:

```
<data xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
</data>
```